# @JsonIgnore does not ignore fields I do not want displaying

Tags: java, json, jackson

This is roughly my code.

I am trying to have Jackson ignore a field when it takes my POJO and creates JSON out of it:

```java
    
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

public class MyPOJO {

    @JsonIgnore
    private String socialSecurityNumber = "111-11-1111";

    // ...

    public String getSocialSecurityNumber() {
        return socialSecurityNumber;
    }

    // ...
}
```

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerationException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

public class FormatAlerts {
    List<Message> alerts = new ArrayList<>();

    public FormatAlerts(List<Message>alerts) {
        this.alerts = alerts;
    }

    public List<String> formatAlerts() {
        List<String> formattedAlerts = new ArrayList<>();

        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            for(Message m : alerts) {
                String alert = om.defaultPrettyPrintingWriter()
                        .writeValueAsString(m);
                formattedAlerts.add(alert);
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return formattedAlerts;
    }
}
```

The JSON is ouputted fine, but the class members that have @JsonIgnore are NOT ignored.

I have these dependencies in my Maven pom.xml

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-xc</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Those are my only Jackson and Json entries in my pom.xml

Do I need a different combination of versions?

Comment: The annotation should be placed on the field, not on the getter.

Comment: I moved the annotations to the top of each field.  Still no joy.
Does it matter if the field is private?

Comment: private is fine as soon as you have public getter

Answer (score 1):

Please add the jackson dependencies as follows. Remove the others.

```
<dependency> 
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.14.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>2.14.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <version>2.14.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I added to my pom.xml and edited my original post.  Still no effect

Comment: I updated my code per your update.  Still no joy.  I also updated my original post with my full dependencies section of my pom.xml.

Comment: But org.codehaus.jackson jackson-xc is still present. Please remove it if possible.

Comment: I did.  It appears I need it to import the ObjectMapper.  Doesn't compile without it.

FormatAlerts.java:[24,31] cannot find symbol
[[1;31mERROR[m]   symbol:   class ObjectMapper

Comment: For ObjectMapper add databind dependency. Check the edited answer.

Comment: Corrected my pom.xml.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Long story short, you are mixing two incompatible libraries.

Jackson project was originally started under Codehaus project, but at least 10 years ago it was moved.

The `jackson-xc` released in 2013 under `org.codehaus` namespace.
You are using an ObjectMapper in `FormatAlerts`

```java
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
```

That kind of ObjectMapper using own `@JsonIgnore` annotation which placed under `org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnore`.

In fact, the ObjectMapper from `org.codehaus` project doesn't recognize the `@JsonIgnore` annotaion from `com.fasterxml` namespace.

You should consolidate those project. I strongly recommend use `com.fasterxml` because `org.codehaus` is no longer maintained.

### Step 1.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-xc</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.12</version>
</dependency>
```

was moved to

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.14.2</version>
</dependency>
```

### Step 2.

Now, the right dependency included, but it has some changes.

Import `ObjectMapper` from the right package

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
```

Don't worry it also have pretty print feature, but the method name changed.

```java
public List<String> formatAlerts() {
    List<String> formattedAlerts = new ArrayList<>();

    // be sure it's imported from com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
    ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();

    try {
        for(Message m : alerts) {
            // changed from om.defaultPrettyPrintingWriter()
            String alert = om.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
                    .writeValueAsString(m);
            formattedAlerts.add(alert);
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```